# Hibernate One to many Persistance

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many

We are getting JSON data from front end to Spring REST controller in the below format,

```
{
"employerName":"ABC Corp",
"employees":[
        {"employeeName":"Rambo"},
        {"employeeName":"Mark"},
        {"employeeName":"Jaicey"},
        {"employeeName":"John"}
    ]
}
```

We have figured out two solutions to map the one-to-many relationship between employer and employee

Solution: 1 (Owner as one side)

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "employer_id")
private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<Employee>();

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "employer_id")
private Employer employer;
```

Solution: 2 (Owner as many side)

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<Employee>();

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "employer_id")
private Employer employer;
```

Now the problem is that first approach fires additional update statements and has been declared unoptimised as per hibernate docs.

The second approach required iteration over employees list and setting value of employer for each employee in rest controller

Please help with the optimised approach to solve / configure the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

CascadeType.ALL performs all actions which are done for one entity also for another entity (create, update, delete, etc..). I guess in your case it is extra usage which causes unnecessary updates and performance issues.

Comment: I agree to you point, but when i try to save employer JSON data with the below mapping definition

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<Employee>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employer_id")
    private Employer employer;

    repository.save(employer);

it saves employer data and employees data but does not creates foreign key i.e. leave employer_id as null.

In this case One to many cascade is not working

Comment: We are using spring rest controller 

`@PostMapping
public Employer save(@RequestBody Employer employer) {
 return employerRepository.save(employer);
}`

but it saves employer data and employees data but does not creates foreign key i.e. leave employer_id as null. In this case One to many cascade is not working

Comment: @AmitPandey have you configured foreign key in database?